# How to find Time Machine disk image?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I try to compact Time Machine disk image but i can't find it. TM is in BackupDisk.

```
$ cd /Volumes
$ ls -1
Macintosh HD
MobileBackups
BackupDisk
$ sudo ls -l BackupDisk/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx@ 0 root wheel 0 Apr 24 11:17 Backups.backupdb
```

I think result of this last command should end up with ".sparsebundle".

How i can find what i need to put to ??? in following code:

```
sudo su - root
hdiutil compact /Volumes/???/???.sparsebundle
```

Comment: As a side remark: `sudo su - root` is kind of overkill, you can just use `sudo -s`.

Answer (score 1):

Time Machine only uses a disk image when backing up to a network destination (OS X Server or Time Capsule). When backing up to a local volume (as you appear to be doing), it stores the backed-up files natively on the volume (inside the Backups.backupdb folder), with no disk image.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using native drive (dedicated USB time machine drive), there shouldn’t be any sparsebundle image.  Therefore there’s no way and no need to do any ‘hdutil compact’ operation.

If you want to free more space for your native time machine drive , you can open the time machine, find the older point of time, and right click, then select “delete backup”